# Ember: Update UI based on model value change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a model that is updated based on an async call. For some reason, the UI does not get updated. Could you point me to why this might be happening. The code is below. I have verified that the code does work if I do not have an async call. I am using ember 2.0. Thank you for your help.

```
App.GroupsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
        var groupsData = [];
         Promise.resolve(Ember.$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/someservice.json',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: JSON.stringify({
                allFor: 'group',
                query: ''
              })
            })).then(function(data) {
                groupsData = data.items;
                return groupsData;
            }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
              console.log('Error retrieving devices data ' + error);
            });
        return groupsData;    
  }
});
```

Comment: how would ember know that variable was replaced?

Comment: You should return the promise, not groupsData. In your `then` portion, you are updating what `groupsData` variable points to but **not** the data that was previously returned from the model. You should just return `Promise.resolve...` and in the `then` just return `data.items`

Comment: wow! wtf are you doing? This is not how you should to query data from backend! Read this! http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html

Comment: please post your handlebar template so we can see what youre accessing from the model and how.

Comment: Thanks returning the promise does work. As for the data query, I was just given this code by the person who developed the back end and I am not entirely sure why they suggested this